# Como fazer uma calculadora imc?

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar functions sem pesquisar na internet, só com a noção das coisas que aprendi, porem não estou conseguindo fazer uma calculadora de imc, da uns numero tudo quebrado. No que estou errando?

```
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];

function imc($altura, $peso){
$altura = str_replace(',', '.', $altura);
$result = $altura * $altura / $peso;
return $result;

}

echo"seu imc é: " .imc($altura , $peso);
?>
```

Comment: IMC não é  = peso em kg / (altura em metros * altura em metros)

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que se vê na internet IMC = peso em Kg dividido pela altura vezes altura, que é a resposta do Caymmi.

Porém existem outras operações que retornam o mesmo resultado:

**1** - usando `pow(x,y)` função retorna x elevado à potência de y, no caso $altura ao quadrado. Veja exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/t2NEIO)

```
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];

function imc($altura, $peso){
$altura = str_replace(',', '.', $altura);
$result = $peso/pow($altura, 2);
return $result;

}

echo"seu imc é: " .imc($altura , $peso);
```

**2** - Inverso de uma divisão. Veja exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/sJk2eS)

> poderia usar também `$result = 1/(pow($altura, 2)/ $peso);`  que retornaria o mesmo resultado.

```
     pow($altura, 2)              $peso
1 ÷  _______________  =  1 x ________________ = $peso/pow($altura, 2)
         $peso                pow($altura, 2)
```

**3** - A partir do PHP 5.6 você pode preferir usar o operador `**`  Veja exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/gQrOaG)

```
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];

function imc($altura, $peso){
$altura = str_replace(',', '.', $altura);
$result = $peso/$altura**2;
return $result;

}

echo"seu imc é: " .imc($altura , $peso);
```

> o resultado pode ser formatado usando a  função [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Uma aula de matemática pelo -1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que multiplicar altura pela altura e depois dividir o peso pela altura.

```
  function imc($altura, $peso){
$altura = str_replace(',', '.', $altura);
$altura = $altura * $altura;
$result = $peso / $altura;
return $result;}
```